# Exponential integral question

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I solve the following problem?
$$f(x)=\int\!\frac{4}{\sqrt{e^x}}\,dx$$

Using $u$ substitution I have set $u=e^x$ andd $du=e^x dx$

so would I have $$4\int\!\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}$$

What would I do from here?

Comment: Your substitution is wrong. It should be $4\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\frac{du}{u}=4\int u^{-3/2}du$. That's easy to integrate. Or you can follow Ron Gordon's suggestion for an even shorter path.

Comment: How did you get $u^{-3/2}$ ? I saw it on wolfram alpha but I dont get it.

Comment: $\sqrt{u}u=u^{1/2}u=u^{1/2+1}=u^{3/2}$. So the inverse is $u^{-3/2}$. You need to work on your exponents! Or you will oftern get stuck.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez : The answer you "accepted" is unnecessarily complicated.  There's a much simpler way.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice: You may use your method, but in doing so, recall that $\color{blue}{u=e^x}$ andd $du=e^x dx \implies  dx = \dfrac{du}{\color{blue}{\bf e^x}} = \dfrac{du}{\color{blue}{\bf u}}$

This gives us

$$4\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\frac{du}{u}=4\int u^{-3/2}\,du$$

Comment: But why would need two U variables that part kind of confuses me I never used such a method.

Comment: Since $du = e^x dx, \implies dx = \dfrac{du}{e^x}$ when we replace dx upon substituting, we have to replace $dx$ by $\dfrac{du}{e^x}$, but $e^x = u$, so we replace $dx$ by $\dfrac{du}{u}$

Comment: Yes that explanation makes sense thanks.

Comment: Comment made more clearly above...

Comment: Then integrating $$4 \int \frac{du}{u^{3/2}} = 4\int u^{-3/2}\,du = 4 \dfrac{u^{-1/2}}{-1/2} = -8 u^{-1/2} + C = -8 (e^x)^{-1/2} + C$$

Comment: I see so my final answer would be -8\int e^{x}^{-1\2}

Comment: Yes...which can be written as $$-\dfrac{8}{\sqrt{e^x}}$$

Comment: I see thanks for your help in this problem it is much clearer to me me now.

Comment: You're welcome, Fernando!

Comment: This method is unnecessarily complicated.  See my answer.

Comment: @Michael, I was simply working out how the OP needed to adjust, give the method HE was using...where IT went wrong. I did not start from scratch.

Comment: @amWhy: I like when people are on point to what the Op asked because they want to know where/why they went wrong using that approach. +1

Answer (score 1):

Stop!  Use law of exponents:

$$\sqrt{e^x} = e^{x/2}$$

Better yet:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^x}} = e^{-x/2}$$

By the way, using your method, you should have a factor of $1/u^{3/2}$ in the integral.

Comment: I the law of exponent the one where you have say (a^n)^m it equal a^(mn)

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: correct.

Comment: So once  you have $4 e^{-x/2}$ how would you get $1/u^{3/2}$ it kind of confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{e^x}= e^{x/2},$$
so you have
$$
\int e^{-x/2} \, dx = \int e^u \,\Big( -2\,du \Big) = -2e^u + C \ -2e^{-x/2} + C.
$$